# Multi threading in PostgreSQL

Tags: multithreading, postgresql

I have a script in PostgreSQL,which takes more time to Execute.

I have a branches in my code which is not related to each other branch.

Here is question,

is there multi threading is PostgreSQL.

since i have a 11-12 branches, I want them to execute simultaneously.

resulting, it'll take less time than the usual.

ex:Presently what I'm doing

```
create function function_name(abc)
    return table(xyz)as
begin

for i  in(1,2,3..12) loop

    if (branch=1)then
        --do branch(1) related work.

    elsif (branch=2)then
        --do branch(2) related work.
    .
    .
    .
    elsif (branch=12)then
        --do branch(12) related work.
    end if;
end loop;
```

Instead of doing the above method, if i could execute all the branches at the same time, it would be much more time saving.

Comment: why you can't just split them into different queries? Any SQL server is by default multithreaded. You can run a lot of queries on it at the same time. Maybe your problem in the code that run this queries? What language do you use?

Comment: @YuriTkachenko Hi, I am using PHP for Querying, But the problem is i'm performing many calculation in Database Stored Procedure Format, and also the loop rows are from same table